# grid-auto-rows repeat

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I have a grid with a variable number of rows. I'm trying to set the height of the rows with `grid-template-rows`:

```
grid-template-rows: 211px 40px;
```

(One row contains thumbnails, and the following contains captions).

Hohwever, with this command only the first 2 rows get resized. I tried with the `repeat` command, but I can't find a way to tell it "repeat n times, where n is the total number of rows divided by 2". For example,

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 211px 40px);
```

only repeats 3 times. If I use `repeat(100, 211px 40px)`, when the real rows end, I get unwanted empty spaces that fill the page at the end.

Is there a way to repeat n times instead of a given value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grid-auto-rows` instead of `grid-template-rows`.

> [***The `grid-auto-rows` CSS property specifies the size of an implicitly-created grid row track.***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows)

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 210px 40px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid .rows {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="rows"></div>
  <div class="rows"></div>
  <div class="rows"></div>
  <div class="rows"></div>
  <div class="rows"></div>
  <div class="rows"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That syntax for grid-auto-rows doesn't seem to work. It only works if I set only one value (all rows of the same height), while if I set two values as you wrote, the heights get bugged: the first caption row is higher, while the other captions smaller, and the rows of the thumbnails are higher than they should be. I checked and that seems to be the default behaviour (I get the same result if I delete grid-auto-rows: 210px 40px).

Comment: @Trial4life as using `grid-auto-rows: 210px 40px` the above snippet is working fine....The issue can be maybe your html markup is different from it...It will be good if you share html as well

Comment: I don't know.... the html markup is pretty complex (I'm making a gallery using Photoswipe). If it can help, I get "invalid property" warning, and the property get canceled, as you can see from this screen: http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vhsxh1&s=9#.Wm8rcnxG270

Comment: Get rid of the `grid-template-rows` rules and try again.

Comment: Firefox does not support track listings, `grid-auto-rows: 210px 40px;` will revert to `grid-auto-rows: default;`.